# convert 4*4 int array into 2*2 int array in c

Tags: c, arrays

I have a 4*4 array-

```
int arr[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4},
                 {5,6,7,8},
                 {9,10,11,12},
                 {13,14,15,16}};
```

want to convert this into 2*2 array -

```
int final[2][2];
```

that should have

```
final[0][0] = (arr[0][0]+arr[0][1]+arr[1][0]+arr[1][1])/4;
final[0][1] = (arr[0][2]+arr[0][3]+arr[1][2]+arr[1][3])/4;
```

Is it possible to extract the value from array using lookup table.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried using the code you've already posted, except without the `, that should have` part

Comment: What is wrong with the code you already have in your question?

Comment: It looks like you already have an answer that works.  Please be precise about what you want from a lookup table.  How much better do you think your code can get?

Comment: *(Wow! its very rare that a user with Rep 1 posts code that is already good and correct!)*

Comment: it looks like you already have the logic you just have to write the loop which populates the new array; I'm not sure what you mean by trying to do this using a LUT

Comment: It looks like in the homework a teacher already wrote the answer, but the OP just can not realize this.

Comment: Want to learn that how to create lookup table for above question if possible as i have browsed to much but couldn't get the satisfactory ans, so i think stackoverflow can help me here.

Answer (score 1):

As has been well commented, you basically have this, but just for completeness:

```
for ( i=0; i<2; i++ )
  for ( j=0; j<2; j++ )
    final[i][j] = (arr[i*2][j*2]+arr[i*2][j*2+1]+arr[i*2+1][j*2]+arr[i*2+1][j*2+1])/4;
```

Comment: want to know, can i use lookup table here to extract the values from given array

Comment: Thanks for above solution, is it possible to create a lookup table for above solution, how to create lookup table for above issue.